# implement Base AsyncTask in Activity and pass results to fragments

Tags: android

Good day, just a quick question. I have an activity that host 2 fragments. now the fragments gets called through buttons in a footer in the activity. In the fragments, i basically do the same thing, start an AsyncTask, parse a JSON response and show in a ListView. The only difference is that some differences in updating certain views in the layouts.

So my question, is there a way i can do the AsyncTask with different constructors from the fragments, in the activity and pass the results to the fragments to update the views? The only issue i can see for now is (if it is an issue), how to know which fragment to pass the data to.

is there a better way or is it fine i do the same procedure in every fragment. Think i worry too much about code duplication

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance!

Pseudo-code for clarification:

SuperFragment:

```
abstract SuperFragment extends Fragment{

    abstract protected void updateLayoutInFragment(..);

    protected MyUpdateTask <...> {

        MyUpdateTask ( int i ){
            // first constructor
        }

        MyUpdateTask ( int i, int y ){
            // second constructor
        }

        @Override
        doInBackground(...){
            // do stuff
        }

        @Override
        postExecute(...){
            if (request was succesfull){
                 updateLayoutInFragment(..);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ChildFragment

```
public class MyFragment extends SuperFragment {

    @Override
    onCreateView(...){
        //startTask
    }

    protected void updateLayoutInFragment(..){
        // fill layout
    }
 }
```